# Details on thunderbolt spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, topology

It's pretty hard to find much details on thunderbolt spacetimes in the literature, beyond the generic topological features (that it corresponds to $\infty$-TIP containing singular TIP), but second-hand sources seem to imply that there is more on the topic.

- What are some example of metrics of thunderbolt spacetimes? The only I've been able to find is this [Physics Forum post](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/wave-of-death.93654/) on the topic, with an example of the metric $$ds^2 = -dt^2 + dz^2 + J_0(\exp(t-z))^2 \, \left( \exp(-2 \, \exp(t-z)) \, dx^2 + \exp(2\, \exp(t-z)) \,dy^2 \right)$$The literature seems to imply that there's quite a variety of them but there never seem to be much in the way of examples.
- A common thing that pops up is that they are often said to be non-scalar null singularities, but this is not present at all in Penrose's original paper on the topic. Where does that assumption come from, and is it justified? Can't the singularity be scalar in nature, or even quasi-regular?

Are there any ressources on those topics? I'm having trouble finding much about it beyond very short mentions or papers not related to those issues.